# How do I reset wave volume and overall volume to max?

Tags: windows, audio

I have tried [Wizmo](https://www.grc.com/wizmo/wizmo.htm) but it doesn't seem to able to reset the wave volume, only the overall volume.

I would prefer it if the solution has a feature (like a command line switch) that will allow it to automatically reset the volume to max each time Windows starts.

**How do I reset Windows' wave volume and overall volume to max?**

---

<sup>Note: This was originally asked for Windows XP. I am currently using Windows 7 and the current accepted answer also works for it.</sup>

Comment: What's the difference between wave volume and overall volume?

Comment: @Stevoisiak Forgot already. It's probably a Windows XP thing. (Maybe I should update this question to only talk about overall volume).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even easier: Use nircmd (http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)

Syntax: nircmdc [device] [left-volume] [right-volume]
"nircmdc" with a "c" at the end is the command line version
0 = mute
32767 = half way
65535 = max volume

```
In your autostart.nt set
nircmdc.exe setvolume 0 65535 65535
nircmdc.exe setsysvolume 0 65535 65535
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Power Mixer**](http://www.actualsolution.com/power_mixer/index.htm) is a replacement for the standard volume control (there are 2 versions, 1 for Vista, 1 for Windows prior to Vista). You can define volume profiles and using parameters on the command line, a profile can be applied. So you can schedule a call to Power Mixer using the Task Scheduler.

[image]

It's not free unfortunately ($17.95), and probably an overkill for your request.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a Autohotkey-Command which sets specifically the wave device: SoundSetWaveVolume
http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SoundSetWaveVolume.htm

And for the system volume you could use the Autohotkey-Command: SoundSet
http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SoundSet.htm

Answer (score 0):

Actually [**wizmo**](http://www.grc.com/wizmo/wizmo.htm) can set both the volume for the wave device and the overall volume:

> volume={0-100}  —  set the system's audio level
>
> If you enjoy associating sounds with system events, you probably grow accustomed to the sounds being at a certain volume level. So, when you need to turn that volume up or down when playing a video clip, or being away from your machine, it is convenient to be able to return the volume to its original level. Wizmo's "volume=" command easily sets the system's volume to a percentage of full volume. Another use for this is creating simple script programs. The example below demonstrates a simple script to turn the volume up while the screen saver is active, then back down after blanking is cancelled.
>
> Exemple: wizmo volume=90 monoff volume=20
>
> wave={0-100}  —  set the system's wave file audio level
>
> The system's wave file playback level can be controlled independently from the overall sound level. The "wave=" command allows this to be independently set.
>
> Example: wizmo wave=25

Comment: I tried this but Wizmo doesn't seem to be able to change Windows XP's wave file volume (I checked volume control to see if the bar moved - it didn't). It can change the main system volume, though.

Comment: @galacticninja, is the correct audio device selected in the Sound control panel applet?

Comment: @Synetech inc. I'm not using Windows XP anymore (I switched to Windows 7), but I do recall that the correct audio device is selected.

Comment: @glacticninja, 7 also has a sound control panel applet. In fact, it is specifically Vista/7 that is the problem because they use a different audio model than in XP, so some (but not all) audio apps will not work correctly if they don’t at least use the correct APIs (like if they do things more directly).

Comment: @Synetech inc. I asked this question back when I was still using Windows XP. Now that I'm using Windows 7, I find that its audio/volume model is a lot better than Windows XP's, since I have no need for NirCmd (the software suggested in the solution I accepted as an answer). This is mainly because each application now has its own independent volume control. Even if one application decides to lower its volume, other applications won't be affected.

Comment: Strange, I could have sworn I specifically saw the question referring to Windows 7. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to mask the problem, you should find and fix whatever program is resetting your WAVE volume when Windows boots.

Sometimes you have to look hard to find these programs, e.g. Irfanview has an optional media/MP3 plugin, if you install this and don't use Windows Media Player, you need to go into the config screen for the plugin and change its audio source from WMP to MCI).  WAVE levels in any program (Winamp etc) that has its own volume control and access to the system mixer must also be checked.

Comment: "Sometimes you have to look hard to find these programs." 
I'm trying to avoid doing this.