# How to reset volume mixer for Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, audio

It is related to [How to reset per application volume setting in Windows 7 and Vista](https://superuser.com/questions/49980/how-to-reset-per-application-volume-setting-in-windows-7-and-vista). Is there any better way to do this in Windows 10?

Answer (score 33):

In your Windows 10 settings, navigate to Sound, and at the bottom of the page, locate "App volume and device preferences" under the Advanced sound options.

From that screen, press the reset button to "reset to the Microsoft recommended defaults."

[image: App volume and device preferences]

Comment: Windows key, "Sound mixer options" (may not need to type the entire name in for it to show up), hit Enter, click Reset. Pleasantly surprised by how quick this is, but the mixer panel really just needs this reset button too.

Comment: Not working. It resets only running apps. But if the app is configured and not running (or maybe not shown in mixer) it's not reset.

Answer (score 2):

I propose a script to automatically reset the audio properties of the Windows 10 mixer.

1. Create a `reset_snd_vol.bat` file
2. Copy-Paste this code:

```
@ECHO OFF

NET STOP Audiosrv
NET STOP AudioEndpointBuilder

REG DELETE "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\LowRegistry\Audio\PolicyConfig\PropertyStore" /F
REG ADD "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\LowRegistry\Audio\PolicyConfig\PropertyStore"

NET START Audiosrv
```

3. (optional) Create a shortcut with admin right

**Explanation**: The script allows you to delete all audio volume settings (of each application) written in the windows registry. It is a hard reset.

It's work for me. I use **Windows 10 x64**

Inspiration: https://youtu.be/AsAhSGJ6s-w

---

There is also a software that proposes to do the same thing but with a UI and configurable with command line options. It is called **NirSoft - AppAudioConfig**

Comment: ...why on earth are _audio settings_ located under the `Internet Explorer` registry key?

Comment: Hello @Dai , i dont know. Microsoft's logic ^^

Answer (score 1):

Another option is the free(as-in-beer)ware third-party Nirsoft AppAudioConfig utility, which lets you edit the saved volume (and L/R balance) levels for all programs on your computer, even if they aren't running:

https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/app_audio_config.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar (although admittedly not identical) issue: The main volume control was unresponsive. Immediately after setting it to a volume, it reset to the previously set volume.

I could solve this by restarting the Windows Audio Services. I'm not sure if it is "Windows Audio" or "Windows Audio Endpoint Builder", since I restarted both by restarting the latter.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).